# Duplicate onmouseover / onmouseout calls for the li tag

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have the following code. (You can copy it into a file to debug in Firefox, and see the outputs in the Console Tab in Firebug).

When I add `onmouseover` envent to the `li` tags, and move the mouse into the `li` area, the console info comes out.

The problem is when I moving the mouse from the image (Google logo) to the text under it, multiple info are print out. Why does the `onmouseout` event triggered, since I don't leave the `li` area?

What should I do to prevent triggering the `onmouseout` events in this situation.

Thank you!!

```
<html>
<body>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li onmouseover="console.info('over')" onmouseout="console.info('out')" style="float:left;display:block;width:30%;height:200px;border: 2px solid red;">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <a href="#">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li style="float:left;display:block;width:30%;">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <a href="#">Google</a>
        </li>
        <li style="float:left;display:block;width:30%;">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <a href="#">Google</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Events **bubble** up the DOM tree](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). So when the cursor leaves the `img` element, a `mouseout` event is generated and triggers the event handler bound to the parent `li` element.

There are **two ways** you can deal with this situation:

**Prevent the event from bubbling**

If you want to prevent the event from bubbling up, you assign an event handler to the element the event originates and call the `event` object's `stopPropagation` method (or `cancelBubble` property in IE):

```
function handler(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // IE
    if(event.stopPropagation) {
        event.stopPropagation();   // W3C
    }
    else {
        event.cancelBubble = true; // IE
    }
}
```

The problem is that you have to bind this handler to every child element, which is not very convenient. Therefore, the following way is easier to realise.

**Test where the event originates**

You can get a reference to the element where the event originates with `event.target` (or `event.srcElement` in IE). The event handler you bind to the `li` element should look like this then:

```
function handler(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // IE
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE

    if(target === this) {   // event originated where the handler was bound to
        console.info('out');
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
onmouseout="handler.call(this, event);"
```

Note that binding the event handlers [inline](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html), like you do, is bad design, as it mixes presentation with application logic. There are [two](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) [other](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) ways to bind event handlers

---

I recommend to read the [articles about event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: yes, in practice, using a js framework will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I had a quick try and found that **Test where the event originates** seems not work (Within the `li` tag, I leave and enter the `img`, `onmouseover` event triggered many times. this is not what I want, since the `img` is **in** the `li`). However, Thanks for your references, I guess I can fix this problem when finishing reading these articles.

Comment: You're welcome :) Make sure you have the setup right. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/LkN8n/

Comment: Well, the image does not take the full width and height of parent element. So when you leave the image, the cursor is over the `li` element again, and the `mouseover` event is triggered on the `li` element. To be honest I don't understand your problem, when do you want `mouseover` to be triggered then?

Comment: Hi Felix, When the cursor move from other part of the `li` to over the `img`, it's also (still) over/within the `li`, in other words, it haven't leave the `li`, so the `onmouseout` shouldn't be triggered. And when the cursor move back to the `li` from the internal `img`, the `onmouseover` shouldn't be triggered either. Treat all the elements in the `li` as part of the `li` (and the events), That's what I want.  Is this requirement odd?

Comment: Ah I see now... I was first thinking that `mouseover` is continuously triggered but I confused it with `mousemove`. In that case, you really have to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, which are only supported in IE, so you'd have to use jQuery. There might be other ways to keep track of this (otherwise jQuery couldn't do it either) but it's not worth the effort imo.

Comment: @FelixKling can you provide the demo .zip for this?

Answer (score 0):

Additional to `onMouseOver` and onMouseOut there is the concept of `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`. Actualy I don't know how it is `implemented` in different browsers. I go with jQuery, which does all the stuff for me. Read all about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), with a great example what's happening when using the different events at the bottom of the page.

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseover` only exist in IE.